# How to split a string into sub strings of n length?

Tags: string, matlab, split

How would i split a string into sub array's of n length in Matlab?

eg.

Input: `"ABCDEFGHIJKL"`, with sub arrays of length 3

Output: `{ABC}, {DEF}, {GHI}, {JKL}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **string length is not a multiple of `n`** you probably need a loop or [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
x = 'ABCDEFGHIJK'; % length 11
n = 3;
result = arrayfun(@(k) x(k:min(k+n-1, end)), 1:n:numel(x), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Alternatively, [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can be used as well:

```
x = 'ABCDEFGHIJK';
n = 3;
result = accumarray(floor((0:numel(x)-1).'/n)+1, x, [], @(t) {t.'}).';
```

Either of the above gives, in this example,

```
result =
  1×4 cell array
    {'ABC'}    {'DEF'}    {'GHI'}    {'JK'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very detailed post and amazing for my use case! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Snel12 Glad I cuold help :-)

Answer (score 4):

This shoud do it :)

```
string = cellstr(reshape(string, 3, [])')
```

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression can do the job here:

```
str = 'abcdefgh'
exp = '.{1,3}' %the regular expression (get all the group of 3 char, if number of char left < 3, take the rest)
res = regexp(str,exp,'match')
```

which give:

```
res =
  1×3 cell array
    {'abc'}    {'def'}    {'gh'}
```

If you only want to match group of 3 char:

```
exp = '.{3}' %this will output {'abc'} {'def'} but no {'gh'}
```

Comment: Good idea! Very clean approach